# How can I pass values to core-plot through an NSArray in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsarray, core-plot

I want to pass data to my core-plot using NSArray. How can I do that?

Comment: What data type are the objects in your array?

Comment: it contains points to be plotted on core plot. So the datatype is float. What can be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iphone, using an array to define in core-plot range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060310/iphone-using-an-array-to-define-in-core-plot-range)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interested in the answer then they can refer to this link:

[iphone, using an array to define in core-plot range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060310/iphone-using-an-array-to-define-in-core-plot-range)